# Zurb Foundation 4 jquery conflict

Tags: 6, theming, javascript

I am working on a Drupal 6 theme which uses the **Zurb Foundation 4 framework**. The problem I have is ideally Foundation 4 requires **jQuery version 1.10.2**.

Drupal 6 only supports up to **jQuery version 1.3.2** using the [jQuery Update](https://drupal.org/project/jquery_update) module. Upgrading site to Drupal 7, unfortunately isn't an option.

I have search through forums and tried a number  of the suggested solutions but I can't seem to get both versions of jQuery to function without either breaking **Core or Zurb Foundation**  functionality.

Comment: Drupal 6 will be out of support really soon. Consider talking to your management about upgrade, really. Without it you will end up with no upgrades and pretty soon issues like that will be your everyday job. If you can't manage to fix them now, while some things are still being updated, how do you imagine doing it then?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [jQuery Multi](https://drupal.org/project/jqmulti) module which provide functionality to load multiple jquery in `Drupal` site.

> **jQuery Multi** allows you to load an extra version of the **`jQuery`** library in parallel to **`Drupal's`** version, without conflicting with **`Drupal's`** version. You can then choose any
>   JavaScript library or files to use the new version of **`jQuery`**. No
>   need to alter packaged jQuery plugins!
>
> - run a newer version of jQuery in parallel to Drupal's without    interfering with things that use the default jQuery version, using
>     jQuery's built in noConflict mode
> - use the newer version of jQuery in custom scripts using the provided    alias
> - configure specific libraries to use the newer jQuery
> - configure any JS file in the system to load using the newer jQuery